# Questions of fermionic coherent states (page 166 of Atland and Simons)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, path-integral, coherent-states

This is quite a basic question but I just can not find the solution.

The question is **how do you show equation (2) below**. Let me explain the details.

From page 166 of condensed matter book by Atland and Simons (https://www.amazon.co.uk/Condensed-Matter-Theory-Alexander-Altland/dp/0521769752) the completeness relation is used to define the fermionic coherent state path-integral. Given some generic state $|n>\in \mathcal{F}$ in the Fock space and coherent state $|\psi>$ which is defined as
$$
|\psi> = \exp\left(-\sum_i \psi_i a^\dagger_i \right)|0> ,~~<\psi| = <0|\exp\left(-\sum_i a_i \overline{\psi}_i  \right)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)
$$
where $\psi_i$ are Grassmannian variables which also anti-commute with the fermionic creation annihilation operators $\{\psi_i, a_j\}=0$. Then apparently one can show that
$$
<n|\psi> <\psi|n>= <-\psi|n> <n|\psi>.~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(2)
$$
Writing left and right-hand sides using the definition (1) one finds
\begin{eqnarray}
LHS &=& <n|e^{-\sum_i \psi_i a_i^\dagger}|0><0|e^{- \sum_i a_i \overline{\psi}_i} |n> ,~~~~~~(3)\\
RHS&=& <0|e^{- \sum_i a_i(-\overline{\psi}_i)} |n><n|e^{-\sum_i\psi_i a^\dagger_i}|0>.~~~~~~(4)
\end{eqnarray}
**I fail to see how equations (3) and (4) are equal....**

Thank you